# update problem in sql

Tags: c#, sql

i have an update statement,which gives an error **"Failed to convert parameter value from a String[] to a String."**

```
SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE count set ETR=@ETR WHERE Id IN ( " + itemIDs + ")", connection);
                comm1.Parameters.Add("@ETR", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                comm1.Parameters["@ETR"].Value = delivery;
```

where itemIDs is an array.now i want to set the value ETR equals to values retrieved from an array "delivery".i mean to say for each itemID there is a value in delivery array and this command shouls set the value of ETR for each itemID to corresponding value in delivery array

Comment: I think we need more code.  What is `delivery`'s type, and what is the value it contains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should preform 1 update command for every item in your delivery, preferrably wrapped in a transaction.

```
SqlTransaction tx = connection.BeginTransaction();
SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE count set ETR=@ETR WHERE Id=@ID", connection);
comm1.Connection = connection;
comm1.Transaction = transaction;
comm1.Parameters.Add("@ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
comm1.Parameters.Add("@ETR", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
for(int i = 0; i < itemIDs.Count; i++) {



    comm1.Parameters["@ID"].Value = itemIDs[i];

    comm1.Parameters["@ETR"].Value = delivery[i];
    comm1.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
 tx.Commit();
```

Comment: thnx for the response,,thnx a lot

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that ItemIds is a string array.  You need to build a function that writes itemIDs to a comma separated string

```
public string ArrayToCsv(string[] arr)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for each(string e in arr)
    {
        sb.Append(e);
        sb.Append(',');
    }

    if (sb.Length > 0)
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I just through that code together from memory, so it might not be 100% accurate, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: i have already done that all i need to do is to set ETR value to each value retrieved from delivery array

Comment: Ah, so if I'm understanding, then delivery is the string array we'ere getting exceptions about.  You will not be able to set a single VARCHAR(50) cell in SQL to an array.  Do you want to set the cell to a comma seperated list?

Comment: why dont u understand the code u have given me is already done,the problem is not in  itemIDs,,u just tell me how can i pass each value of delivery array to ETR

Comment: Remember, your query UPDATE SET is setting one row at a time, so you must build your query so that it sets a single cell in a single row..

Comment: how about using  `string.Join(", ", itemIds) `  - that basically already does all you're doing, and it's part of the base classes....

Comment: @sumit: He misunderstood you because you were terribly unclear when you originally described the problem you were facing.

Answer (score 1):

> comm1.Parameters.Add("@ETR",
>   System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
>   comm1.Parameters["@ETR"].Value =
>   delivery;

Your parameter "@ETR" is a single string. The thing you're assigning to it "delivery" is an array of strings, as you say yourself. That won't work - ever.

You need to rethink your logic somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement is expecting a comma separated string especially with IN.
Just pass the array to a function which takes the array and changes 123456 into 1,2,3,4,5,6
and passes it back.

Comment: the problem is not in itemID ,its in statement comm1.Parameters["@ETR"].Value = delivery;
as ETR is a string and delivry ia an array and i want to pass each value of delivery in ETR

Answer (score 0):

> he problem is not in itemID ,its in statement comm1.Parameters["@ETR"].Value = delivery; as ETR is a string and devilry ia an array and I want to pass each value of delivery in ETR

Like in one record with all values, or different records?

Using one record, you need to parse the string array to csv or the like.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string s in Delivery)
{
    sb.Append(s);
    sb.Append(",");
}
sb.Remove(sb.Length-2,1).ToString();
```